# The name of the type of words like "party" and "quest"

Tags: terminology

My company often comes up with product names such as "HatQuest" "DataParty"

as a programmer I wish to make a generator for these types of names, How would I best find a list of words for things like "party" and "quest".

I can't really use verbs since "DataSit" or "HatOpen" don't really work and nouns are inappropriate since there are so many of them.

What kind of words am I looking for so I can obtain a list of them?

Comment: You can look for synonyms for both words.  The lists will be different, of course, because "quest" and "party" are not synonymous.

Comment: 'Quest' and 'party' are usually put in what is often considered a subset of nouns, 'abstract nouns'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for synonyms. Like, do [these](http://thesaurus.com/browse/quest) work for you?

If you're not looking for something like that (or you're looking for something at merges quest and party somehow), try using a [reverse dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml). It might not work perfectly, but maybe you'll find a word that you like and then you could find synonyms to that word.